How can I fuzz loosely parallel applications with afl-plusplus
afl-fuzz -i  -o  -M ms1 -- ./
Additional binaries are "slaves" of master, so that the fuzzing campaign can perform cooperative descent across multiple cores.
But what if the application(s) I am fuzzing require more than one heavy weight executable?  If not supported yet, is this support envisioned in the near term?  If not a single afl-fuzz(er) then afl-fuzz can run against each executable with the one taking input from the fuzzer the master.  Master fuzzer expects a handshake from slave fuzzers before -T(imeout) or else process a signal (hang or crash) accordingly.
